# php echo inside echo and textbox

Tags: php, forms, echo

How to get $test value inside php echo?

line 7:

```
<?php function writeMsg() {
echo "</form>";
echo "<form name='input' action='index.php' method='get'>";
echo "<table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='600' height='400'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td height='560'><textarea class='textarea' name='xml' cols='83' rows='37'>";
echo "$test";
echo "</textarea></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td height='40' align='center'><input type='submit' value='PRENESI XML'></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
}
?>
```

Any solution would be great. Thank you

Comment: Don't put in in the "" just do echo $test

Comment: This question doesn't make sense to me. Please, clarify a bit what you want to achieve.

Comment: @KamRon that's nonsense, this would work if $test had any value.

Comment: It sounds more like you need a definition for `$test` than anything else.

Comment: @mightyPork I see that now, quickly looking I just saw that.

Comment: `$test` is undefined in your function, so it'll never show up as anything other than a null (which prints as an empty string).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the OP's example literally, `$test` needs to be defined in order for `echo` to output anything. Also, the function will not do anything unless it is invoked.

```
function writeMsg() {
   $test = "foo";
   echo "$test";
}
writeMsg();
```

Output:

```
foo
```